# PHP app in subdirectory in Nginx

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, Nginx 1.10.3 and PHP 7.0. The example PHP applications are CodeIgniter 3.1.5.

I am trying to run a static page at the root of my site www.example.com(works) with multiple other CodeIgniter applications each running in subdirectories at www.example.com/client-a, www.example.com/client-b, etc.

The static page at my root runs fine, however when redirecting to the apps at the sub directories none of the stylesheets and scripts get loaded resulting in 404 errors. The routing works though.

The application files of the subsequent apps don't exist within one another.The application root exists in `/var/www/example/public_html` while the "nested" applications lives in `/var/www/client_a/public_html`, `/var/www/client_b/public_html` etc.

Here is my Nginx server block:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;    
    root /var/www/example/public_html;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;       

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location /client-a {
            alias /var/www/client_a/public_html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @nested;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            }
    }

    location @nested {
        rewrite /client_a/(.*)$ /client_a/index.php?/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires 30d;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you have set for `base_url()` in clients' applications? Do you load assets with prepending `base_url()` i.e. `base_url('assets/css/style.css')`?

Comment: `base_url()` = www.example.com/client-a and I prepend it when loading the assets.

Comment: It is mandatory to use (AFAIK) scheme and trailing slash. `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/client-a/';`. [Docs](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L4-L26).

Comment: I tried that however it doesn't seem to work

Comment: You are getting 404 for CSS files. What is non-found URL in browser console inspector?

Comment: You need to use `location ^~ /client-a` otherwise the nested location will not be found.

Comment: Thank you @RichardSmith that solved my issue